# Why does my network interface's name change when I plug a different PCIe device?

Tags: network-interface, networkmanager

My integrated RJ45 network card has an interface called `enp5s0`, if I plug a graphics card, it becomes `enp6s0` messing all the configurations I've done.
I'm often plugging unplugging PCIe devices and it's becoming seriously annoying to manually change all the devices in my network configuration.

=> How to stop this non-sense? obviously I'm not moving the RJ45 interface anywhere.. why does RHEL8 change its name depending on other devices?

- https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/html/configuring_and_managing_networking/consistent-network-interface-device-naming_configuring-and-managing-networking

> By default, consistent device naming is enabled in Red Hat Enterprise Linux.

This isn't true since the name changes depending on other devices...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Consistent" doesn't mean "permanent". PCI-E devices are enumerated by BIOS first, so plugging something in may change the order.

Please follow https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/html/configuring_and_managing_networking/consistent-network-interface-device-naming_configuring-and-managing-networking#assigning-user-defined-network-interface-names-using-udev-rules_consistent-network-interface-device-naming

And create your `/etc/udev/rules.d/70-custom-ifnames.rules` to have persistent names for NICs with certain MAC addresses.

Comment: Do you know the name of the BIOS setting to have consistent bus number for each PCIe device? I'd like to avoid creating user-defined name...

Comment: There's no such setting in BIOS unfortunately. If you had thousands of devices you could ask for a BIOS update to solve this issue.

Comment: Ok... too bad, that's really annoying and only this motherboard does that... (Asus W790E-SAGE SE)

Comment: I've seen this behaviour with multiple motherboards, ASUS and ASRock included :-)

Comment: Too bad BIOS' devs aren't more consistent..